# Get Image URL/Address from webpage selection using Applescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, applescript, automator, imageurl

I need a quick way to get the image URL, just like I would get if I right click on an image and select "Copy Image URL".  I'm thinking Applescript, though others have mentioned Javascript.

This needs to be compatible with an Automator workflow and needs to work with Google Chrome, Chromium, and Safari, at a minimum.

More specifics:

1. I already have an Automator workflow that this will be added to.
2. The workflow begins with text and images that I have selected on a webpage using the mouse.
3. The processing of the text is working fine.
4. I just need a Applescript or Javascript or Shell Script (which I assume are the only outside code that can be added to an Automator workflow) that will grab any and all image URL's within the part of the page selected in step 2.
5. Images are NOT downloaded.  Only the image URL is needed.

The basic logic is this:

```
Does selected input contain images?
    If yes, 
    get URL of image(s) 
    pass to the next step
else continue
```

Any help or ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OS X Services would be your best bet. Those work with text selections and are supported in most apps (e.g. see the Safari>Services submenu). You can also assign them keyboard shortcuts, which is very handy for repetitive tasks.

Basically, you want to get the selection as web content (i.e. HTML data, not plain text) then extract the URLs from that. You can create services in Automator, which includes various actions for working with web content, so I recommend starting there.

Comment: OK, if I'm reading this correctly (and I might not be), you're suggesting this can be done in Automator.  I do know that you can process all image URLs in Automator (as long as you're not processing text at the same time).  I tried getting all image URLs in Automator at the same time I'm getting text, and it didn't work.  

This is why I specifically asked for another solution.  Plus a Safari only solution wouldn't work in this case, since the workflow I already have works with Safari, Chrome, and Chromium.

Comment: I'm saying it can be done using Services. You can write Services in Automator (assuming you can find suitable Actions) or you can write them in Xcode (assuming you know ObjC). Automator-built services can get the selected text in a variety of formats, including 'web format'. What I can't tell you is if there's an Action that'll take 'web format' as input and output the HTML markup as a string (which is presumably what your URL extraction code takes), so you'll have to find that out yourself.

Comment: Re. Chrome/Chromium, I don't use it on Mac, but I'd be surprised if it didn't support Services too - most apps do (e.g. Firefox does).